# How do I move NAN values to the end of a pandas dataset after sorting?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a merged dataset that has been sorted by column. After the sort I wanted to move the NaN values to the bottom of the dataset. How can I achieve this?

Example:

```
name age country
joe  NaN UK
NaN  23  USA
Jill 46  UK
```

to

```
name age country
joe  NaN UK
Jill 46  UK
NaN  23  USA
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try with `na_position = 'first'`:

```
df = df.sort_values('age', na_position= 'first')
```